# Finding a basis of $S \otimes_R N$ with $N$ a free $R$-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, tensor-products, free-modules

Let $S$ and $R$ be commutative rings with $f: R \to S$ a ring morphism. Suppose that $N$ is free $R$-module with basis $B$. I want to understand why $N \otimes_R S$ is a free $S$-module where the action is given by $s'\cdot (n\otimes s) = n \otimes s's$.

It's easy to see that $B$ generates $N \otimes_R S$, but I'm having trouble showing directly that $B$ is linearly independent over $S$. Perhaps there is an easy way to do this via the universal property of tensor products, but I'm unsure. Or perhaps I'm looking at the wrong set altogether.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The basis deduced from $B$ is $\;\{e\otimes 1_S,\;e\in B\}$.

Comment: @Bernard Yes, exactly.

Comment: You can prove it's a basis by a relevant isomorphism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a couple possible approaches: pick your favorite.

- Show that $\bigoplus_{b \in B} S$ satisfies the universal property of $N \otimes_R S$, using the $R$-module homomorphism $N \to \bigoplus_{b \in B} S$, $\sum_{b \in B} \lambda_b b \mapsto (\lambda_b)_{b \in B}$.
- Use the universal property of $N \otimes_R S$ to conclude that for any $R$-linear functional $\phi : N \to R$, there exists a unique $S$-linear functional $\tilde\phi : N \otimes_R S \to S$ such that $\tilde\phi(x \otimes \lambda) = \lambda \cdot \phi(x)$ for $\lambda \in S$, $x \in N$.  Now, if you have a basis $B$ for $N$, and $\sum_{b\in B} b \otimes \lambda_b = 0$, then apply this with the dual elements of $N^* = \operatorname{Hom}_R(N, R)$ to conclude that $\lambda_b = 0$ for all $b$.

Comment: For the first approach, to show that $\bigoplus_b S$ is a universal object, don't we need a bilinear map $N \times S \to \bigoplus_b S$?

Comment: Oh, I was thinking of $- \otimes_R S$ as being the scalar extension functor, and as such as being adjoint to the scalar restriction functor.  (Which is in fact equivalent to the definition as a tensor product.)  The corresponding $R$-bilinear map $N \times S \to \bigoplus_{b\in B} S$ would be $(\sum_{b\in B} \lambda_b b, \mu) \mapsto (\mu \lambda_b)_{b\in B}$ (where $\lambda_b \in R$, $\mu \in S$).

Comment: In case you might not be familiar with adjoint functors: what I mean is that I view $N \otimes_R S$ as the $S$-module with an $R$-module homomorphism $N \to N \otimes_R S$, such that for any $S$-module $M$ and an $R$-module homomorphism $N \to M$, there is a unique $S$-module homomorphism $N \otimes_R S \to M$ such that the composition $N \to N \otimes_R S \to M$ results in the given map $N \to M$.  (This $S$-module is then unique up to unique isomorphism.)

Comment: I'm actually confused now. What do you mean by $\lambda \cdot \phi(x)$?

Comment: It means that $f : R \to S$ makes $S$ into an $R$-algebra, so you can multiply $\lambda \in S$ and $\phi(x) \in R$ to get an element of $S$ (technically, you would get $\lambda f(\phi(x))$).